# How to determine the number of terms in $(x+\frac{1}{x}+1)^n$

Tags: binomial-theorem

I just wanted to know, how can I calculate number of terms in $$\left(x+\frac 1{x}+1\right)^n?$$

My try:

Any term of the expression will be of the form $(x)^i(\frac{1}{x})^j(1^k)$, and if in any term  if $i=j$ then it will become a constant term. I also tried to write the expression as $\frac{x^2+x+1}{x}$ but i don't know what to do know.

Please keep it simple and write how you got there. I just have no idea.

Thank you.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yeah i wrote that but it was of no help.

Comment: Try $n=2$, how many terms do you get? What are they?

Comment: @SamSharma: As a suggestion, write down the things you've tried in your question to avoid receiving information you already know (such as Thomas' comment).

Comment: @Clayton i have edited it.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews please help.

Comment: Note that $x^i(\frac1x)^j1^k = x^{i-j}$. You're probably supposed to collect all terms with the same power of $x$ into a single one. How many different values of $i-j$ are possible?

Comment: @HenningMakholm how can i determine that?. Sorry i am new to this.

Answer (score 8):

**Hint:** Our expression is equal to $\frac{1}{x^n}(x^2+x+1)^n$.

The number of terms is the same as the number of terms in $(x^2+x+1)^n$.

Imagine expanding $(x^2+(x+1))^n$ using the Binomial Theoremm $a=x^2$, $b=x+1$. We will get $x^{2n}$ plus a bunch of lower degree terms.

How many terms? There can't be any more than $2n+1$ terms, because each term will have shape a constant times $x^k$, where $k$ is any of $0, 1, 2,\dots,2n$.

Persuade yourself, and the reader, that there are no "missing" terms, that is, no coefficient of an $x^k$, $k=0$ to $2n$, is equal to $0$. Here we are helped in the argument by the fact that the coefficients of $x^2+x+1$ are positive, so on multiplication nothing can cancel.

**Added:** Your approach also works well, but some detail has to be filled in. We get a large sum. Before we **simplify**, they are of shape $x^i\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)^j 1^k$, where $i+j+k=n$. As you pointed out, when we simplify, some of these combine. For example, $x^1(1/x)^1(1)^{n-2}$ will become $1$, as will quite a few others, when $n$ is at all large. And there will be several ways to end up with an $x^1$, also several ways to end up with a $(1/x)$, which I will call $x^{-1}$.

What is the **biggest** power of $x$ that we get? By choosing $i=n, j=0,k=0$ we get $x^n$. By choosing $i=0,j=n,k=0$ we get $x^{-n}$. That's the smallest (most negative) power that we get. Between $n$ and $-n$, inclusive, we have $2n+1$ numbers (don't forget $0$).

We want to see that we get a term in **every one** of these powers. By symmetry, it is enough to show that we get stuff in every non-negative power of $x$, from the $n$-th power to the $0$-th power.

For $0\le m\le n$, we get $x^m$ in the expansion, for example by using $i=m,j=0,k=0$, and usually in several other ways. But the point is we do get some stuff that involves $x^m$. So every power of $x$, from $x^n$ down to $x^{-n}$ is represented, a total of $2n+1$.

Comment: I am sorry but i am not able to understand this, can you give another way round.Thank you and +1 for your help.

Comment: I will be away for a while. In the meantime, perhaps you can indicate in a comment which one(s) of the $5$ short paragraphs of the answer give you trouble.

Comment: The second para says: The number of terms is the same as the number of terms in $(x^2+x+1)^n$ but there is also x^n as denominator will it not cancel some terms in numerator and it will become constant.

Comment: Also in the third:how does expanding $(x^2+(x+1))^n$ gives x^2n plus a bunch of lower degree terms and also i am not able to understand third and fourth. I am sorry, but thank you for your effort. If you don't mind can you check what i have tried and where can i go from there. Thanks.

Comment: The point is that the highest term is $x^{2n}$ as you say.  The lowest term is $1=x^0$.  You will have one term for each exponent $0$ through $2n$, making $2n+1$ of them.  There is no need to compute the actual terms to solve this problem.